# Find the most granular level of any level parent in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

My Table structure is

```
 | Parent ID   |  ID         |
 |-------------|-------------|
 |      a      |     b       |
 |      b      |     c       |
 |      b      |     d       |
 |      b      |     e       |
 |      c      |     f       |
 |      d      |     g       |
 |      e      |     h       |
```

I want to get the most child node for all parent . 
In a other table I have a , b and c . Then I want to get the below result .

```
 |  Parent_ID  |  Child      |
 |-------------|-------------|
 |      a      |     f       |
 |      a      |     g       |
 |      a      |     h       |
 |      b      |     f       |
 |      b      |     g       |
 |      b      |     h       |
 |      c      |     f       |
```

f , g , h are the lowest granular .

Comment: [One question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348681/find-the-most-child-node-of-a-parent-any-level-in-oracle) is absolutely enough

Answer (score 0):

first you should make sure you are using Oracle vision 10g or higher and then use connect_by_isleaf, and you can try to learn more about connect_by

```
select connect_by_root a.id as id,a.parent_did
  from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id=b.id 
   where connect_by_isleaf = '1'
   CONNECT BY PRIOR a.parent_did = a.id;
```